# How to bind MDTextField input with Label's text on second screen

Tags: python, kivy, label, kivymd

I have started creating small app and I'm stuck. I tried many different ideas from this forum but nothing fit my app. I'm already confused how should I do this.
All I want is to take the input from MDTextField (which is provided by user) and show it in the Label's text on the Second Screen.

My .kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    First:
    Second:

<First@Screen>:
    name: 'screen1'
    MDTextFieldRound: 
        id: getpath
        text: "Enter player name"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 300
        mode: "rectangle"
        icon_right: "scissors-cutting"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Submit"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen2'
<Second@Screen>:
    name: 'screen2'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'image.jpg'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        id: lab
        text: ''
```

My main.py:

```
class PKNApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        pass


PKNApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an `id` for `First` `Screen` in your `kv`, like this:

```
ScreenManager:
    First:
        id: first
    Second:
```

Then you can use that `id` to access the `TextInput`, like this:

```
Label:
    id: lab
    text: root.manager.ids.first.ids.getpath.text
```

Comment: Yeesss! Thank you, it is exactly what I needed!